# How do I format a "Delete object from Firestore" function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete an object, inside an array, inside an object, inside an array, in firestore. This is the object below I'm trying to delete, as shown with a blue arrow:

[image]

Here is my current attempt in code to delete this. For reference:

activeLabel = 0, and i = 0

```
const deleteCard = async (name, tags, i) => {
    const fieldRef = doc(db, "user", currentUser.uid);
    await updateDoc(fieldRef, {
      labels: arrayRemove(activeLabel, {
        cards,
        [i]: {
          name: name,
          tags: tags,
        },
      }),
    });
  };
```

Here's and error I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function arrayRemove() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document user/KFmRwdjoigh3qipoehg
```

After seeing a comment I need to re-work my entire function. Here's the updated code below:

UPDATE:

I've now tried to create better logic to filter out the object I want to delete. Here's my code now:

```
  const deleteCard = async (name, tags, i) => {
    // READ FIRESTORE DATA
    const removeCard = labels.labels[activeLabel].cards[i];
    // MODIFY DATA
    labels.filter((card) => {
      card === removeCard;
    });
    // WRITE DATA BACK TO FIRESTORE
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), labels);
    getCards();
  };
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Try logging all the values and you can find the undefined one. Also what you are trying to do is not possible for nested arrays. You can't just remove just one item from cards directly,,

Comment: Would I need to read the firestore data, update it as in filter out the object I want to remove in state, then re-write the data to firestore?

Comment: Yes, that'll be the solution. `arrayRemove()`  could be used if you are removing entire object from the parent array

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj. I added some updated code to my question. Now I'm getting an error. I can't seem to filter out the object I want to remove so that I can re-write the data to firestore. Any advice on my new logic in the createCard function is greatly appreciated.